# Performing math on a list of tuples Python

Tags: python, list, nlp, tuples

I have a list for tuples, and I want to find the difference between the third element of each tuple and the third element of the tuple preceding it in the list.

```
 x =   [(206, 205, 206),
 (206, 208, 209),
 (206, 409, 410),
 (206, 521, 522),
 (2206, 560, 562),
 (206, 605, 607)]
```

for the above example what I am looking for is `(206-209),(410-522),(522-562)` ect.

Is what I am looking for possible?

(for context the tuples are the result of a Phrase Matcher search in spacy, where I am looking for a list of terms, and trying to find the distance between terms)

Comment: Do you want to all possible differences? I mean (206 - 209), (206 - 410), ..., (562 - 607).

Comment: No, because the list is in order i am only looking for the distance between the two next to each other

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()`

```
res = [a[-1] - b[-1] for a, b in zip(x, x[1:])]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[-3, -201, -112, -40, -45]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're good with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
x =   np.array([(206, 205, 206),
 (206, 208, 209),
 (206, 409, 410),
 (206, 521, 522),
 (2206, 560, 562),
 (206, 605, 607)])
```

You can do it also using `numpy` 2D slicing:

```
x[:-1, 2] - x[1:, 2]
```

or use `np.diff` that is designed to calculate preceeding differences:

```
-np.diff(x[:,2])
```

#### Output:

```
array([  -3, -201, -112,  -40,  -45])
```

You can use `arr.tolist()` or `list(arr)` to convert it to list if you need it later.